# Black-Litterman proof with P=I and Omega=tau*Sigma

Tags: asset-allocation, black-litterman, proof, derivation

Elsewhere on this site ([link](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16280/black-litterman-how-to-choose-the-uncertainty-in-the-views-omega-for-smooth?rq=1#)), Richard notes that 
\begin{equation}
\Pi_{BL} = \frac{1}{2} \Pi + \frac{1}{2}Q,
\end{equation}
so long as we set $ P = I $ (where $I$ is the identity matrix) and $\Omega = \tau\Sigma$. This result seems relatively straightforward and intuitively obvious, but in trying to derive it I tend to end up with $\Pi_{BL} = \Pi + Q$.

Can someone provide a derivation? Or, at least, maybe sketch a proof so I can see what I might be missing? Thanks,